# my azure pipeline is not running. how do i delete an agent pool in azure pipeline

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZAjQ.jpg)This agent request is not running because you have reached the maximum number of requests that can run for parallelism type 'Microsoft-Hosted Public'. Current position in queue: 1

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? As far as I know, you can not delete an agent pool in azure. But, first of all, provide more details, please.

Comment: OK. Thank you Pawara I will post the images now.

Comment: i have added a link to the image

Comment: The quality of the question is poor. Try to follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @jazzbass it is great you make the suggested edits. but try to provide a clear explanation when posting questions although you are in a hurry. It results in downvoting your post by the community and perhaps you may not get answered. I went through similar types of issues found in other forums. but in each case provided description is very low. So, difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: @Pawara thank you for the feedback i have made the adjustment.